# Regex - Match up to next match in groups

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string that I want to split up using a regex:

`Connect: Unable to open connection to server. HOST:(servernamex) SERVICE:(cnxadaB0) DATABASEINFO:(3 255 C:\DATABASENAME.DAT) ERROR:RemoteConnect: SocketError(10061) The CONNX Listener process (CNXRUN##_MAIN) is not running on the system.`

The regex I have come up with up to now is as follows:

```
(\s|^)([A-Z]\w\w+:(?!(\s[A-Z]\w\w+:)))
```

When I run the regex I get the following result:

> ```
> MATCH 1 
> 1. '' 
> 2. 'Connect:' 
> MATCH 2 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'HOST:'
> MATCH 3 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'SERVICE:'
> MATCH 4 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'DATABASEINFO:' 
> MATCH 5 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'ERROR:'
> ```

I want to split it up using regex to group the data for me as follows:

> ```
> MATCH 1 
> 1. '' 
> 2. 'Connect:' 
> 3. 'Unable to open connection to server.'
> MATCH 2 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'HOST:'
> 3. '(servernamex)' 
> MATCH 3 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'SERVICE:'
> 3. '(cnxadaB0)' 
> MATCH 4 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'DATABASEINFO:' 
> 3. '(3 255 C:\DATABASENAME.DAT)' 
> MATCH 5 
> 1. ' ' 
> 2. 'ERROR:'
> 3. 'RemoteConnect: SocketError(10061) The CONNX Listener process (CNXRUN##_MAIN) is not running on the system.
> ```

Sample with what I played with:
[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(^|\s)([A-Z]\w+:)\s*(.*?(?=\s[A-Z]\w+:|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/2)

In case you want to avoid first captured group with space or empty string then use lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=^|\s)([A-Z]\w+:)\s*(.*?(?=\s[A-Z]\w+:|$))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([^: ]+?:(?![^(]*\)))\s*(.*?)(?=\s+[^: ]*:(?![^(]*\))|$)
```

You can use this.See demo.Instead of `split` do a `match` and capture `groups`.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/3